# Как обеспечить уникальность коллекции объектов?

Tags: java, android, коллекции

Есть `ArrayList` значений. При добавлении новых данных вся новая коллекция всегда попадает в исходный список.
Как от этого избавиться?

Кейс: на экране есть список, по пул ту рефреш новые данные добавляются. Они могут быть точно такими же, что мы уже загрузили. Как сделать так, чтобы повторений не было?

```
for (Items item : response.body().getItems()) {
    if (!mItems.contains(i)) {
        mItems.add(i);
    }
}
```

Переопределил эти методы. Не помогает.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    Ad ad = (Ad) o;

    if (getSlug() != null ? !getSlug().equals(ad.getSlug()) : ad.getSlug() != null)
        return false;
    if (getLat() != null ? !getLat().equals(ad.getLat()) : ad.getLat() != null)
        return false;
    if (getLng() != null ? !getLng().equals(ad.getLng()) : ad.getLng() != null)
        return false;
    if (getKind() != null ? !getKind().equals(ad.getKind()) : ad.getKind() != null)
        return false;
    if (getTitle() != null ? !getTitle().equals(ad.getTitle()) : ad.getTitle() != null)

    ....

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = getId();
    result = 31 * result + (getSlug() != null ? getSlug().hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (getLat() != null ? getLat().hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (getLng() != null ? getLng().hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (getKind() != null ? getKind().hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (isPremium() ? 1 : 0);
    result = 31 * result + getRoomsAmount();
    result = 31 * result + (getTitle() != null ? getTitle().hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (getSpace() != null ? getSpace().hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + getImagesAmount();
```

Пробовал решения наподобие:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
// add elements to al, including duplicates
Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
hs.addAll(al);
al.clear();
al.addAll(hs);
```

Не работает.

Comment: если hashSet содержит дубликаты, значит у вас неправильный hashCode и equals(). Оставьте в этих методах только те поля, равенство которых для вас означало бы равенство объектов.

Comment: Оно у вас в многопоточной среде работает?

Comment: Да, в многопоточной. В активити делаю запрос ретрофитом, в колбеке вызываю runUiThread и туда элементы записываю

Comment: @Adeptius пробовал так же и без вызова runUiThread

Comment: Если `HashSet` содержит *"дублирующиеся"* элементы, значит вы неправильно определили метод equals() Для этого класса. Именно он определяет в  HashSet уникальность элемента

Answer (score 2):

Значит обьекты, которые вы ложите в лист имеют разный хэшкод и виртуальной машиной читаются как разные, хотя данные обьекта, как вы считаете - одинаковы.
Тогда вы должны написать свой алгоритм по которому у вас будут сравниватся объекты. Например вы можете реализовать у вашего обьекта `Item()` интерфейс `Comparable<Item>`. 
И в реализованном методе `compareTo(AnotherObject)` напишите свою логику сравнения.
В сигнатуру метода будет попадать второй обьект для сравнения.
Он должен возвращать отрицательное число(если обьект меньше), 0(если оба идентичны), положительное число(если обьект больше другого).
А потом ложите его в структуру, которая поддерживает работу с компаратором. Например `TreeSet<>()`.
Вот вам пример класса Woman:

```
public class Woman implements Comparable<Woman>
{
 public int age;

 public Woman(int age) {
  this.age = age;
 }

 public int compareTo(Woman o) {
  return this.age - o.age;
 }
}
```

`TreeSet<>` будет вызывать этот метод каждый раз при вставке нового элемента.
Если вы правильно напишите алгоритм сравнения - дубликаты исключены.

Например вы можете у вашего `Item()` сравнивать ключевые поля. Если это стринг - можете использовать `equals()`. если он возвращает true - возвращайте 0 из метода `compareTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении элемента в `ArrayList` никакой встроенной проверки на уникальность нет. Поэтому возникают дубликаты.

Для хранения уникальных элементов используйте `HashSet`. Для этого нужно чтобы `equals` и `hashcode` были определены и использовали одинаковые поля (это похоже у вас сделано).